# Are flowers important?

Tags: terraria-mobile

I want to know if flowers are just decorations or are actually important. I do know that some flowers can be made into dye(Sky blue flower, etc...).
Is collecting them necessary? Should I collect the seeds and plant them as well?

Comment: it's probably worth keeping them if you just happen to pick them up and then just have a chest to store them all, just in case you might like them for something later, but if you run out of inventory on a  journey they'd be one of the first things that I would throw out. Having plant farms, using the seeds, would look nice, but wouldn't be very necessary.

Comment: I would especially recommend keeping daybloom, as it's used in most of the battle potions, I believe. Or at least the substantial basic ones.

Comment: If the answers are satisfactory, you can select an answer on this.

Answer (score 3):

In the desktop game, plants are used for potions. They can be farmed to mass produce potions, or collected on your travels for low effort harvesting. I would highly recommend keeping them, although some you'll find are simply inventory fillers.

Comment: While potions are awesome if you use them, I can attest that it's completely possible to beat the game without ever using any potion other than health and mana ones. I have two chests full of potions I have found in my adventures and I never use them, because I'm a hoarder... Wormhole potions are amazing in multiplayer though.

Comment: @Chippies It's definitely possible. I also tend to hoard them as well, but when I remember I have them, it can really help, especially against bosses. Swiftness potion is one to always have against a boss as there's virtually no downside. Other potions such as the gravity potion may have complex effects that make fighting bosses difficult but can give you an edge when used correctly.

Comment: Iron skin and regeneration potions (don't remember exact name of it) are always useful as well, but there's just so many types of potions that are useful that, unless you actually grow them all and invest a lot of time in making the potions, it can be quite overwhelming. If you do have the potions and aren't afraid to use them, they're great help and can change the outcome of any boss battle.

Comment: @Chippies I used a bunch of pots to make daybloom, and quite frankly, I was turning out potions. Not fast enough to use on a daily basis, but I used them for boss fights, which made a huge difference. It's not too difficult to farm in terraria, but it does take a bit of time.

Answer (score -2):

Yes they are important. They are used to make lots of potions in the game. Keep all of them, or you'll regret it later on.